# How to upload react-native image from expo-image-picker to Express.js backend that is using multer

Tags: react-native, express, expo, multer

as title says, I am trying to upload picture using expo-image-picker and express.js backend

Expo code:

```js
const openImagePickerAsync = async () => {
  let permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
  if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
    alert("Permission to access camera roll is required!");
    return;
  }
  let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
  const dataa = Object.values(pickerResult);
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('image', {
    path: dataa[2], //image uri
    originalname: "profilePic" + userId + ".jpg",
    type: "image/jpg",
    fieldname: "demo_image"
  })
  console.log(data)
  const uploadImage = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/upload/picture/` + userId, data);
}
```

#### Express code

Router:

```js
var multer = require("multer")
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    console.log(file)
    cb(null, './controllers/assets/profilePic/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    console.log(file)
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
}).single("demo_image");
router.route("/upload/picture/:userId").post(upload, UserController.updatePhoto)
```

updatePhoto function:

```js
static updateGamePhoto = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const query = await GamMdl.find({
      game_id: req.params.gameId
    })
    console.log(req.file)
    if (query.length > 0) {
      //get file route
      //get route to db
      const queryy = await GamMdl.updateOne({
        game_id: req.params.gameId
      }, {
        picture: req.file.originalname
      })
      console.log(queryy)
      res.send("1")
    } else {
      //vymaz file
      fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path)
      res.send("0")
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
2022-04-10T18:17:29.165105+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined
2022-04-10T18:17:29.165435+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'originalname')
2022-04-10T18:17:29.165436+00:00 app[web.1]:     at updatePhoto (/app/controllers/userController.js:166:119)
2022-04-10T18:17:29.165436+00:00 app[web.1]:     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
2022-04-10T18:17:29.165439+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Which most likely means, that object is not being passed or is unable to be parsed correctly.

When I test uploading image only with backend using Postman all works well.
Postman preset:

[image: postman preset]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use axios for file upload because you need to read the image from the native filesystem. You can use `uploadAsync()` from the `FileSystem` module from Expo. [Documentation Here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemuploadasyncurl-fileuri-options)

In your case the function call would be:

```js
const openImagePickerAsync = async () => {
  let permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
  if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
    alert("Permission to access camera roll is required!");
    return;
  }
  let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
  if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
    const uploadResult = await FileSystem.uploadAsync('http://localhost:8000/upload/picture/1', pickerResult.uri, {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      uploadType: FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART,
      fieldName: 'demo_image'
    });
  }
}
```

By the way, avoid using localhost since the app may run on a device or emulator, and localhost would be the device itself instead of your webserver. Pass the API endpoint via environment variables. More info [here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/). Use something like `dotenv` to load variables during development.